# "Ignore and continue" while debugging on Visual Studio (2008 & 2010) in C# possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to "Ignore and Continue" instead of "Restart" and "Edit" when a C# file in your solution changed while debugging?

Way to reproduce it:

1. I have a solution that contains project A and project B.
2. While debugging project A, I make changes to project B (a typical example is network client/server debugging session).
3. Carry on debugging session on A becomes impossible (eventhough the code is totally unrelated in terms of execution) if "Edit" fails.

I searched in VS options without much luck.

Splitting the solutions into multiple solution file is not an acceptable answer (I have files as links and I already do that and it proves unconvenient due to libraries and dependency... that is the whole point of having a solution file in the first place)

Comment: There is a setting to set allow running code to differ from source code. However once the code changes while the code is running Vs.Net balks at the changes, as long as the changes aren't loading in Vs.Net you should be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undo your changes (Ctrl+Z) and press F5 to continue.

If you want to retain your changes for later use, you can keep them in the clipboard or restore them using Ctrl+Y later.

I assume that an ignore option does not exist because it does not make much sense to debug source code that has become out of sync, e.g. the debugger would no longer highlight the correct lines etc.

Comment: That is work around indeed, except that I need to compile my changes to the client code and run again on the running server that doesn't need to change. C++ does it well with purple lines of code when outdated code, why can't C# simply do it as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are by design limitations of the *Edit & Continue* feature.

Here is a list of them for VS 2010:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx

Comment: I don't want to EDIT and continue. I want VS to ignore my change to the source code and continue.

Comment: In that case, it's not possible (and reasonable).

Comment: Then C++ is more reasonnable then :)